# linq to List problem in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, list

I have class Zones with properties and i want add data which i read with linq to this properties.

example

```
List<Zones> z = new List<Zones>
z.add(new Zones(...));

var allZones = from s in db.Zones select s;
```

How can i add allZones to z generic List?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in a number of ways:

```
z.AddRange(allZones);    // if there are other elements in z
z = allZones.ToList();   // if there are no other elements in z (creates a new list)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
allZones.ForEach(x => z.Add(x));
```

or

```
z.AddRange(allZones.ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

If allZones is IEnumerable<Zones> the you can use

```
z.AddRange(allZones)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
z.AddRange(allZones.ToList())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var z = db.Zones.ToList();
```

Then add any new zones to the list.

or

```
z.AddRange(db.Zones);
```

Answer (score 1):

`z=db.select(X=>X.Zones).ToList()`